# Angular: Adding multiple values for routing

Tags: angular, typescript

When using a `routerLink` or `router.navigate` I have an array that contain multiple values that will be serialized into `?id=val1&id=val2`, but we cannot set an optional route parameter to an array to contain multiple values such as `;id=val1&;id=val2`

```
param['products'] = [];
param['products'].push(1);
this.router.navigate(['',param]) // works
param['products'].push(2);
this.router.navigate(['',param]) // does not work
```

I also tried `this.router.navigate(['', [...param]])` but doesn't work

Comment: maby param['products[]'].push(2); will help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this way

```
this.router.navigate(['users'],{ queryParams: { param1: val1,param2: val2 } });
```